# Getting Null Values if the For Loop iteration doesnot exist in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have few static key columns EmployeeId,type and few columns coming from first FOR loop.

While in the second FOR loop if i have a specific key then only values should be appended to the existing data frame columns else whatever the columns getting fetched from first for loop should remain same.

**First For Loop Output:**

```
"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","","",""
```

**After Second For Loop i have below output:**

```
"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","AMAZON","1",""
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","FLIPKART","2",""
```

As per code if i have Employee tag available , i have got above 2 records but i may have few json files without Employee tag then output should remain same as per First Loop Output.

But i am getting 0 records as per my code. Please help me if my way of coding is wrong.

Really sorry -- If the way of asking question is not clear , as i am new to python .  Please find the code in the below hyper link

**Please find below code**

```
    for i in range(len(json_file['enty'])):
        temp = {}
        temp['EmployeeId'] = json_file['enty'][i]['id']
        temp['type'] = json_file['enty'][i]['type']
        for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'].keys(): 
            if(key == 'Employee'):
                for j in range(len(json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'])):
                    for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'][j].keys():
                        try:
                            temp[key] = json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'][j][key]['values'][0]['value']
                        except:
                            temp[key] = None

                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
                    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], sort=True)
```

If Employee Tag is not available i am getting 0 records as output but i am expecting 1 record as for first for loop

[enter link description here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=672e1c8e543047a5a236d44c589f6476)

Comment: Don't post code as images

Comment: @barbsan .. I just edited the question by pasting the code..  Is that fine .. ? Please help me with any suggestion

Comment: @barbsan .. Added sample source Json file as well.

Comment: @ can some one please please help me to solve this issue.